# Load modules conditionally Python

Tags: python, dynamic-loading

I wrote a python module that needs to  load a file parser to work. Initially it was just one text parsing module but I need to add more parsers for different cases.

```
parser_class1.py

parser_class2.py

parser_class3.py
```

Only one is required for every running instance. I'm thinking load it by  command line:

```
mmain.py -p parser_class1
```

I wrote this code in order to select the parser to load when the main module is called:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import argparse
aparser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
aparser.add_argument('-p',
            action='store',
            dest='module',
            help='-i module to import')
results = aparser.parse_args()

if not results.module:
    aparser.error('Error! no module')
try:
    exec("import %s" %(results.module))
    print '%s imported done!'%(results.module)
except ImportError, e:
    print e
```

But, I was reading that this way is dangerous, maybe not standard.

Then is this approach ok?

Or must I find another way to do it?

Why?

Answer (score 4):

## Regarding the safety aspect of your question.

The reason why `exec()` can be dangerous is that is can allow a nefarious agent to execute code that you never intended.

Let's assume for example that somewhere in your program, you have sensitive data elements such as:

```
username = secret_username
password = never_share
```

And let's also assume that someone calls your program like this:

```
mmain.py -p 'parser_class1;print globals()'
```

Then your `exec()` statement would actually be:

```
exec("import %s" %('parser_class1;print globals()'))
```

*And this would result in your program printing out all variables in your global space for them...* **including your username and password.**

By making your program utilize the `__import__` method as mentioned by @Jaime, you can at least prevent people from executing non-import statements in your code.

But, you should, whenever possible also examine the input from a user before using it to execute any dynamic code.

Answer (score 3):

#### Sanitising your inputs with argparse

As has already been mentioned in comments and @eikonomega’s answer, running arbitrary code from the user is generally dangerous. Using `__import__` or `importlib` restricts their ability somewhat.

You can make it even safer by restricting the set of available modules, by passing a `choices` flag to `add_argument`. Like so:

```
aparser.add_argument('-p',
            action='store',
            dest='module',
            help='-i module to import',
            choices=['parser1', 'parser2', 'parser3'])
```

argparse will now enforce that only the values "parser1", "parser2" or "parser3" can be entered here – anything else will cause it to exit and print a usage message, e.g.:

```
$ python conditional_imports.py -p foo
usage: conditional_imports.py [-h] [-p {parser1,parser2,parser3}]
conditional_imports.py: error: argument -p: invalid choice: 'foo' (choose from 'parser1', 'parser2', 'parser3')
```

It’s also better for the end-user, because the help/usage message will tell them the available options, rather than leaving them to guess.